# instantiate instances of tcpdf laravel 4

Tags: pdf, laravel, laravel-4, tcpdf

how to instantiate instances of TCPDF on laravel 4, I already added `"tecnick.com/tcpdf": "dev-master"` on my `composer.json` but i Dont know what to do next. I added this code on my controller:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Text(90, 140, 'This is a test');
$filename = storage_path() . '/test.pdf';
$pdf->output($filename, 'F');

return Response::download($filename);
```

but i get `Class 'TCPDF' not found` error.. Please help me on this one. I cant find any comprehensive documentation on how to implement this on laravel4. I also already tried dompdf but it consumes too much cpu when generating pdf files. I did also tried wkhtmltopdf but its just too hard to implement due to unavailability of comprehensive documentation for laravel4 for beginners. Thanks for the help. I would really appreciate any advice and help from you guys!

Best Regards!

-melvn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I just did here:

Required it using Composer:

```
composer require "tecnick.com/tcpdf" "dev-master"
```

Ran dump-autoload

```
composer du
```

Used it in a testing route:

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{

    $pdf = new TCPDF();
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Text(90, 140, 'This is a test');
    $filename = storage_path() . '/test.pdf';
    $pdf->output($filename, 'F');

    return Response::download($filename);

});
```

[And it worked](http://puu.sh/5EcgU.png)

Take a look at vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php to see if the TCPDF is there, if it is, it should work for you too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @antonio Carlos! but im having this weird error, do you whats happening here? i got this error : ` Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)  `

Comment: Odd. I didn't and I just checked (php --info), it's not installed.